# Title tag loaded by JS document.title function not changing title tag in source view

Tags: javascript, onload

I am currently running the following js on some of my pages to dynamically set the title tag on the page pulling from the h1 tag contained on that page.

`document.title = document.getElementsByClassName("Category-H1")[0].innerHTML;`

However, when I view the page's source, it still shows the old title tag, even after the js has changed it.

It was suggested to me that I might have to add an "onload event of the body", not sure if this would help, or what onload event I would need to run.

Any other ideas? Suggestions?
Thanks - Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'source' is just that ... it is the code returned from the server. In most cases to see DOM changes made after loading you will need to look at the code in Firebug or Chrome Inspector.

Comment: You are right! Firebug is showing the updated title tag. Thanks.